# Activity function should return an IEnumerable<IListBlobItem>

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, ienumerable, azure-durable-functions

I have an activity function which should return an `IEnumerable<IListBlobItem>` as follows:

```cs
[FunctionName("process_file_GetBlobList")]
public static IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> GetBlobList([ActivityTrigger] string name, ILogger log)
{
    string storageConnectionString = @"connstring";
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container");
    IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = new IListBlobItem[0];

    foreach (IListBlobItem blobItem in container.ListBlobs())
    {
        if (blobItem is CloudBlobDirectory)
        {
            CloudBlobDirectory directory = (CloudBlobDirectory)blobItem;
            blobs = directory.ListBlobs(true);
        }
    }

    return blobs;
}
```

In my Orchestrator I am calling this activity function as follows:

```
 IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = await context.CallActivityAsync<IEnumerable<IListBlobItem>>("process_file_GetBlobList", null);
```

by debugging I get no error message, but in run time I get this message:

> failed: Could not create an instance of type
>   Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.IListBlobItem. Type is an interface or
>   abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path
>   '[0].StreamWriteSizeInBytes'

Do have any idea, how can I call my activity function via `CallActivityAsync`?

Comment: The exception is being thrown on which line?

Comment: In this line: `IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = await context.CallActivityAsync<IEnumerable<IListBlobItem>>("process_file_GetBlobList", null)`

Comment: You could create a class of your own, put the relevant data you need there, and return that.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to List and see,

```
  List<ListBlobItem> blobs = await context.CallActivityAsync<List<ListBlobItem>>("process_file_GetBlobList", null);
```

however, you can fix the above error by changing the blobs to type var.

Comment: Tnx, but doesn't help. still the same error message

Comment: what is the type of class you had?

Comment: https://github.com/fbeltrao/SignalRAndDurableFunctions/blob/7d31bbcc9eac9a7a123f0da2c416595f3db1be21/src/FlightSearchFunction/FlightSearchOrchestration.cs

Comment: I have such a definition for my class in which I have the function: ` public static class process_file`. hopefully, I have understood your question

Comment: you need to create a class as i showed in the code and change the return type to that

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are having list of Interface which definetly can't be initialized.  You can create a new class implementing IListofBobItems and then return List of newly created class from GetbobList method

Comment: I would be very thankful, if you could show me how can I implement your idea

Comment: If you can share structure of IListOfBobItems then i can write some codes for you

Comment: I am using a c# library which generates `IlistBlobItem` (as you can see in my question ) I didn't write it by my self

Answer (score 0):

I believe the line `IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = new IListBlobItem[0];` needs to be rewritten. try `IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = new List<IListBlobItem>();`